# Assistance needed in finalizing SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am stuck in writing SQL code for this sample data

```
Dummy Col   AcctSK      AcctrelatedSK   
--------------------------------------
9999        11465399    -1          
9999        11465399    11401099
```

In the above sample data I have one `acctsk` but in actual code that I am writing it is returning lot more different `acctsk` values, but in the same behavior as mentioned above.

What I am trying to achieve is if the count of some `acctsk` is greater than or equal to 2 then return only value in `Acctrelatedsk` other than -1. The code is returning correct result when there is only one `AccountSk` however when multiple `Acctsk`, I am not able to figure that part out.

---

More Sample Data

```
9999 11465399 -1
9999 11465399 11401099
9999 11465404 -1
9999 11465404 11401099
9999 11465405 -1
9999 11465405 11401099
9999 11465440 -1
9999 11465440 11401665
```

Expected result

```
9999 11465399 11401099
9999 11465404 11401099
9999 11465405 11401099
9999 11465440 11401665
```

Comment: Can you add some more sample data and expected output

Comment: Can't you just use WHERE AcctrelatedSK > -1 ?

Comment: Hey Prdp, Please find the below sample with expected result       --Sample Data
9999 11465399 -1  
9999 11465399 11401099 
9999 11465404 -1 
9999 11465404 11401099
9999 11465405 -1 
9999 11465405 11401099
9999 11465440 -1
9999 11465440 11401665 
--Expected data
9999 11465399 11401099
9999 11465404 11401099
9999 11465405 11401099
9999 11465440 11401665

Comment: Hey Jeff, I cant use that condition is because its valid value for single Acctsk.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting stuff into the comments

Comment: So if there is (lets say) 4 rows with same ``AcctSK`` and one of them has -1 in ``AcctrelatedSK`` you are expecting 3 rows ? I Agree that a well formated expected result would help us to help you ;)

Comment: We are not a code writing service. You do not ask for "finalizing"; you ask us to do everything because you show zero effort from yourself. Elance, Odesk as where you hire people to do your job.

Comment: You should show the table name (it never fails to astonish me that people ask SQL questions with sample data but no table name — but it is a common fault).  You should show what you've tried (which would also reveal the table name).  You ask for help 'finalizing' a query, but as far as we can see you've not even started. You should show the results you get from your best attempt, and explain why what you get isn't what you need.  Also, add information to the question, not the comments; you can format the information in the question but can't in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @DummyTable Table (DummyId int, Acctsk int, AcctrelatedSK int)

insert into @DummyTable 
values(9999, 11465399, -1),
(9999, 11465399, 11401099)

select top 1 dt.Acctsk, dt.AcctrelatedSK from (
select Acctsk
from @DummyTable dt
Group By Acctsk 
Having Count(Acctsk) >= 2) as temp
join @DummyTable dt on dt.Acctsk = temp.Acctsk
where dt.AcctrelatedSK != -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you need, but maybe something like this:

```
select * from (
  select
    *, dense_rank() over (partition by AcctSK order by case when AcctrelatedSK = -1 then 1 else 0 end) as RANK
  from
    yourtable
) X where (AcctrelatedSK != -1 or RANK = 1)
```

The rank handles selecting either the other rows or -1 when it's the only row

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback James, It worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (
    AcctSK int,
    AcctrelatedSK int,
    Count int
);

INSERT INTO @temp (AcctSK, AcctrelatedSK, Count)
SELECT 
    AcctSK,
    AcctrelatedSK,
    ( SELECT count(1) FROM DataTable WHERE AcctSK = OriginalData.AcctSK ) AS Count
FROM DataTable AS OriginalData 

SELECT *
FROM @temp
WHERE Count = 1
  OR (Count >= 2 AND AcctrelatedSK > -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (
SELECT *,
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY AcctSK ORDER BY CASE WHEN AcctrelatedSK = -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) rn
FROM YourTable) x
WHERE x.rn = 1;
```